# How can I auto generate a class with static members based on annotations (similar to Android's R) class

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

Assume I have this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Config {

} 

@Config
public class ConfigA {
    public static final String FOO_A = "A";
}

@Config
public class ConfigB {
    public static final String FOO_B = "B";
    public static final String SOMETHING_ELSE = "SE";
}
```

I want to auto generate a class looking like this:

```
public class Result {
    public static final String FOO_A = "A";
    public static final String FOO_B = "B";
    public static final String SOMETHING_ELSE = "SE";
}
```

Ignoring the chance of conflicts how can I achieve that?

The final goal is to auto generate Result with Gradle depending on the build type/flavour and since I am using Eclipse creating a builder which generates Result to be able to use the members in the source. (Like the R file in Android projects is generated from XML files but I don't want to use XML)

Comment: This is called Java Annotation processing: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+annotation+processing&oq=java+annotation+processing&aqs=chrome..69i57.3615j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Create a separate project (e.g., named `codegen`) to contain the class generation logic. In there, I'd use [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to scan for classes that are annotated with `@Config`, add all their members to a list, and eventually output a class with those members using [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or a similar templating library.
2. Put your `@Config` annotation and the class you're going to annotate into their own Gradle project, e.g., named `config`.
3. In your build.gradle file, create a task (e.g., `processConfig`) that runs the templating tool on the classes generated from #2.
4. Have the Gradle project that's going to consume the templated output (e.g., named `solution`) depend on `processConfig`, and add its output to a custom SourceSet.

As long as you've configured your source sets correctly, and made sure that the main source set depends on your intermediate source set, the rest of the `solution` build should just work.

Alternatively, there are more involved approaches using ASM or cglib to generate bytecode directly that would also work.